# WPF: Focus behavior on tab item change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following problem: In the UI of my C#/WPF/MVVM application I have a TabControl in the MainView that contains multiple Items. In one of thos items a DataGrid is placed for data manipulation of a database.

I encounter the following problem which might be a focus problem: When I am editing a cell then change to another tab and close the program the change is not saved to the db. When I just change to another tab and go back again I can see that the DataGrid's cell is still in edit mode. So my assumption is that the state of the TabItem's content is preserved during the change to another tab and then restored after I change back and so the DataGrid never loses focus thus the values are not saved to the database.

Does anyone have a suggestion how this can be solved using a MVVM compliant pattern (possibly only using xaml)?

Comment: I don't think this is a focus issue. The user has to hit <Enter> to commit the changes. Or you have to end the edit mode by force when the the user switches to a new tab. In most scenarios the user should commit or cancel changes. Unless the changes are committed they won't propagate back to the view model. Maybe you should provide more implementation details.

Comment: I'm not sure because when I click on the active tab or another control the DataGrid loses focus and the changes get saved. Only when the tab is changed the focus stays and the controls stays in edit mode.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to provide a code sample because the xaml is split into several ContentControls. Perhaps I'll manage to write a minimal example which shows the problem this afternoon.

Comment: Up to you. The normal behavior is that when the focus moves away from the `DataGrid` e.g. switching the tab the current edit gets committed (when there are no validation errors).